# FragmentActivity﹕ Activity result delivered for unknown Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, google-play-services, google-api-client

The google api call below is not producing any callbacks. There is only a warning that 'FragmentActivity﹕ Activity result delivered for unknown Fragment.'

```
        mClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addApi(Fitness.SENSORS_API)
                    .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_ACTIVITY_READ_WRITE))
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(
                            new GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks() {
                                @Override
                                public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
                                    Log.i(TAG, "Connected!!!");
                                    // Now you can make calls to the Fitness APIs.
                                    findFitnessDataSources();
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
                                    // If your connection to the sensor gets lost at some point,
                                    // you'll be able to determine the reason and react to it here.
                                    if (i == GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks.CAUSE_NETWORK_LOST) {
                                        Log.i(TAG, "Connection lost.  Cause: Network Lost.");
                                    } else if (i
                                            == GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks.CAUSE_SERVICE_DISCONNECTED) {
                                        Log.i(TAG,
                                                "Connection lost.  Reason: Service Disconnected");
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                    )
                    .enableAutoManage(this, 0, new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
                            Log.i(TAG, "Google Play services connection failed. Cause: " +
                                    result.toString());
                            }
                 })
                .build();
        mClient.connect();
```

Comment: did you register your mClient in findFitnessDataSources()?

Comment: well thats a different case, "Connected!!" tag is not appearing meaning findFitnessDataSources() won't execute either

Comment: .enableAutoManage requires extend,ng FragmentActivity What do you extend in this activity/fragment?

Comment: Alternatively you can manage connection failure by urself via .addConnectionCallbacks(new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener(){.....}).build();

Comment: Facing the same issue.

Comment: @hXT1022 Did you find solution ? Facing the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this was the OP's issue, but in case anyone else encounters the above warning, check any startActivityForResult calls you make **within** your fragments. In my case, I moved these calls from the activity to a fragment, and left them as they were. However, when made from inside a fragment, you need to call getActivity() first, as in:

```
getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent, RESPONSE_CODE);
```

Failing to do this results in the "Activity result delivered for unknown Fragment" error and no responses being delivered to the Activity to process.

Answer (score 0):

Try downgrading your support libraries to 23.1.0 if you using anything higher than that.

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution for this issue after struggling a lot. New API is released and this issue is resolved in it. So just update your build.gradle file with:

> compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-fitness:10.0.0'